# Creating Predictions From Base Regressor Models in a Boosted Machine

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, adaboost

So I'm writing my own implementation of AdaBoost using chapter 10 of Elements of Statistical Learning.  The pseudocode given in the book lists how to make the algorithm for a classification problem, but not a regression problem.  I'm creating my own AdaBoost regressor, and the details of how to make predictions from your base models is surprisingly hard to come by.

The documentation at SciKit Learn lists the [paper by Ducker](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.31.314&rep=rep1&type=pdf) as a reference, but I'm having a hard time parsing exactly what to do with it.

It's stated in the paper that you take the weighted median for your final prediction, which is defined as follows:

[image: Definition of weighted median]

I assume this means:

For every sample in your dataset:
Find the prediction among your base regressors with a value Bt that has an equal number of values above and below it, and use the associated regressor associated with that value of B_t.

However, I find this confusing because the above definition doesn't make any reference (as far as I can tell) from the actual predictions made from the regressors themselves.  And since there's a separate value Bt for each base regressor, wouldn't the above definition amount to choosing a prediction from a single regressor and then using that one's prediction for the entire dataset?  That seems like a bad idea.

Intuitively, what I think would happen is that we have some list of values for `Bt` sort of like this:  `[2.45, 0.73, .29, .18, 1.6]`

Then we'd make a weighted prediction from each of our base models, and choose the median prediction at each row, corresponding to those weights.

For a small example, with 5 samples and 5 base predictors:

```
# values of Bt for each base regressor
B_t = np.array([2.45, 0.73, 0.29, 0.18, 1.6])
# random predictions
preds = np.random.RandomState(42).choice(100, size=(5, 5))
# get weighted predictions
B_t /= B_t.sum()
weighted_preds = B_t * preds
```

And then something like:

```
# pseudo numpy/python code
# get the index of the median value for each row
med_idx = get_index_of_median(weighted_preds, axis=1)
# use those index values to get the appropriate median value from each of your rows of initial predictions
median_pred = [row[idx] for row, idx in zip(preds, med_idx)]
```

This seems a bit more intuitive to me, although I digress I might be way off.

Would love some pointers on this issue.  Thank you.